# How can I retrieve function names and attributes from Python code with AST?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Given a piece of code like this:

```py
aaa = bbb()
ccc.ddd().eee(fff(foo))
ggg(bar)
hhh().iii
```

I would like to get something like this:

```
['bbb', 'ccc.ddd.eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh.iii']
```

I'm aware of the `visit_Call` and `visit_Name` methods, but I can't get them to return only function names or function names with functions called on objects returned by those functions (like foo().bar()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce function-attribute lookup paths, you will want to traverse the `ast.AST` object, checking for any `ast.Call`s or `ast.Attribute`s, and if any are found, you will then need to walk those objects, saving the names and attributes as they occur. The recursive pattern below traverses the main `AST` (`parse`) and utilizes a helper function (`parse_chain`) to walk any attributes or calls for names present:

```
import ast
def parse(d, c):
  def parse_chain(d, c, p=[]):
     if isinstance(d, ast.Name):
        return [d.id]+p
     if isinstance(d, ast.Call):
        for i in d.args:
           parse(i, c)
        return parse_chain(d.func, c, p)
     if isinstance(d, ast.Attribute):
        return parse_chain(d.value, c, [d.attr]+p)
  if isinstance(d, (ast.Call, ast.Attribute)):
     c.append('.'.join(parse_chain(d, c)))
  else:
     for i in getattr(d, '_fields', []):
       if isinstance(t:=getattr(d, i), list):
          for i in t:
             parse(i, c)
       else:
          parse(t, c)

results = []
s = """
aaa = bbb()
ccc.ddd().eee(fff(foo))
ggg(bar)
hhh().iii
"""
parse(ast.parse(s), results)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
['bbb', 'fff', 'ccc.ddd.eee', 'ggg', 'hhh.iii']
```